# Composer dependency for specified PHP version

Tags: php, composer-php

is it possible to tell composer to install a dependency only when using specified PHP versions?

Reason: my library uses password_hash function, which is available in 5.5+, and there is a compatibility library ircmaxell/password-compat for PHP 5.4. However installing this library on PHP 5.5+ is completely pointless. So, Is it possible to tell composer to install ircmaxell/password-compat only when running on versions <5.5?

Short story to make the question more clear - I want to tell composer to:

```
IF php version < 5.5:
    install ircmaxell/password-compat
ELSE:
    skip ircmaxell/password-compat
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Please posts only direct answers how to do this, not any workarounds or suggestions to drop 5.4 support. I can also come up with them, I am looking for the smart solution here :)

Comment: Yes look at this http://odino.org/managing-php-dependencies-with-composer/

Comment: I think your best bet is taking a look at the [scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) property and working something out with that.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Maybe I'm missing something, but I can't find anything in that article that answers the OP's question?

Comment: Yes, I also don't see an answer :) I hope I made my question clear, I will try to clarify more

Comment: `There are 3 main parts in the composer.json,` Look at PART 3 `"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.2",
    "kriswallsmith/Buzz": ">=0.5"
}` But I may be wrong

Comment: @RiggsFolly this says that the project NEEDS php >= 5.3.2, not to install something IF php is running on >= 5.3.2. But thanks for your try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "It's not possible".

The dependency is not a massive one. Why not simply let it install anyway? If you are on PHP 5.5 the built-in password functions will still be used.

You could also make `password-compat` an optional dependency (`suggests`). The issue then is that it's up to the maintainer to install it alongside your application.

Lastly, you could make a secondary, virtual package. Say your package is called 'Acme', It would be possible to create a secondary 'Acme-php54' package that depends on *both* password_compat and your main project. This keeps the dependency outside of your project, but I would argue that the simplest is to just always install it as long as you intend to support PHP 5.4, and just drop PHP 5.4 in a little while when it EOLs.

Comment: Yes, I see that it is not massive and I will do that if I won't get suitable solution here. I want to keep my project clean, this is why I'm asking for this.

Comment: Well thanks for more thoughts :) but 1) making it an optional dependency is not very nice, needs end user to think, complicates travis build. 2) making a secondary package doesn't solve the problem, the decision logic if to install it or not is still missing. 3) I am curious if this is possible in general, yes I can also come up with many similar workarounds :)

Comment: See the 'short answer' part then ;) Pretty confident in that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

Consider having one branch, e.g. 1.x for legacy php versions, like

```
{
    "name": "some/library",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "require": {
        "ircmaxell/password-compat": "*"
    }
}
```

and 2.x branch for 5.5+

```
{
    "name": "some/library",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5"
    }
}
```

This way loose version requirements, i.e. `some/library:*` will resolve to appropriate versions.

Another way is to instruct the users to add

```
"replace": {
    "ircmaxell/password-compat": "*"
}
```

by themselves if needed.

Note that some users (including myself) can change their php interpreter on the fly and won't be too happy to debug this kind of automagical issues.

Comment: Well, thanks, this looks as most close approach, however I also don't like this kind of automagic so I won't do it if it is not possible to do in a cleaner way.